# Obtener el estatus de una base de datos en PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

¿Cuál es la forma de obtener el estatus de una base de datos en PostgreSQL?

Sé que en SQL Server se obtiene desde `sys.databases`, pero no he encontrado algo similar en PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT name, is_read_only, state_desc, recovery_model_desc  
FROM sys.databases;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que puede obtener información similar consultando algunas funciones de el catálogo, por ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT current_database() datname, pg_is_in_recovery() as read_only,current_setting('archive_mode') archive,current_setting('wal_level') wal_level;
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte